# How to describe "something on which a decision has to be made"?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Context**

The term will be used to describe items in a list presented together with options / possible solutions (e.g. *material:* wood, steel or aluminium?).

**Example**

When designing a piece of furniture, one has to decide on:

- overall shape and structure
- dimensions
- materials

*How to accurately describe the items in the bullet points?*

**Ideas so far**

- question
- (decision) point
- factor
- (sub-)problem
- issue

Are there better options?

***edit*** Some more ideas: aspect, facet, detail, component.

Comment: Sometimes these are just called “*the particulars*”

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **criteria**, plural of **criterion**, which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criteria) defines as:

> 1 : a standard on which a judgment or decision may be based

Comment: Your suggestion makes lot of sense to describe the items during the actual decision-making process, specifically when making judgments and considerations. It's not the best fit for the context in which I will be using it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps call them 'variables'. It sounds somewhat mathematical, but is (I think) precise, and correctly used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **options**.  "Please select your preferred options from the list below."

You can also use the word Specifications is typically applied when describing the aspects of a product.